# Getting errors while trying to install packages through pip

Tags: pip

I am getting errors below while trying to install packages through pip. Could you please help me getting rid of them?

[image: screenshot of error produced while installing package through pip]

Comment: Please don't add text as screenshots, instead copy and paste text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

as in docs:
https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.13/installation.html
please install with:

`python3 -m pip install sounddevice --user`